# How can I take my navigation to the right of screen?

Tags: css, navigation, css-float

I can't put my navigation menu to the right of screen. I used a lot of CSS but so it's a bit hard to find where is my mistake.

This is my html code:

```
<div id="main-container">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="header">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li ><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
                    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="pictures">
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the CSS i have trouble with:

```
 #main-container {

    }
    #content {
        background-color: #FFAA00;
        background: url(images/table-surface-2-resized.jpg) repeat-x #000000;
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #header {
        background-color: #FFD200;
        width: 800px;
        height: 26px;
    }
    #pictures {
        background-color: #A64D00;
        width: 760px;
        height: 540px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 14px;
    }

    /*  TABS WITH ROUND, OUT BORDERS */
    #nav {
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 24px;
        height: 26px;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: verdana;
        position: relative;
            }
    #nav li {
        border: 1px solid #AAA;
        background: #D1D1D1;
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 1px 0 #FFF;
        text-shadow: 0 1px #FFF;
        margin: 0 -5px;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    #nav li.selected {
        background: #FFF;
        color: #333;
        z-index: 2;
        border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    }
    #nav:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: " ";
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #nav li:before,
    #nav li:after {
        border: 1px solid #AAA;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -1px;
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        content: " ";
        }
    #nav li:before {
        left: -6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
    }
    #nav li:after {
        right: -6px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
        box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
        }
    #nav li.selected:before {
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #FFF;
    }
    #nav li.selected:after {
        box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFF;
    }

    #nav a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    /*  END TABS WITH ROUND, OUT BORDERS */
```

Comment: try giving `float:right` to `#nav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try out this css (addition)

```
#nav {
  padding: 0 10px;
   float:right;
}
```

here is working [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/2bhwY/1/)

Comment: Thanks Uttara. Accidently i have added float:right to the #nav li so i thought something was wrong (:

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: http://dabblet.com/gist/3435951

Float `#nav` to the right, give it a right margin, remove `overflow: hidden` from it and add it on the `#header`.